# Showing limit of a derivative is finite

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

Given that a function $f$ is continuous on interval$\left[a, b\right]$, and that its derivative is finite everywhere on that interval except possibly at $c$. I am also given that $lim_{x \rightarrow c} f'(x) = A$, and I want to show that $f'(c) = A$.

My attempt:
By definition of $lim_{x \rightarrow c} f'(x) = A$, we have that $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ s.t. $|x-c|<\delta \implies |f'(x) - A| < \epsilon$

Since the function f is differentiable everywhere, mean value theorem tells us that $\exists x_0 \in (x,c) $ s.t. $f'(x_0) = \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$. The right hand side is defined (if it exists which it does since $x_0 \neq c$) as $f'(c)$ if we take the limit going to $c$. So then we have $lim_{x\rightarrow c} f'(x_0) = lim_{x\rightarrow c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} := f'(c)$ ? Not really sure if this is right or where to go from here

Comment: I think you can use Darboux's theorem here; the derivative is a Darboux function, so that, if it was discontinuous at some point, either the left- or right- hand limits would not exist:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Comment: And, actually, you seem to be assuming in your argument that f is differentiable everywhere, which is what you want to prove. Maybe all those "Full House" episodes are getting to you. I think I made a similar mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the derivative is finite". Do you mean that it may not exist at $c$?

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much correct.  For $y_x$ the value you get from MVT on the interval $(x,c)$, we see

$\lim_{x\rightarrow c} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} = \lim_{x\rightarrow c} f'(y_x) = A$